# Java annotation processor- fields of field

Tags: java, annotations

I am writing custom `annotation processor` and have been looking for a way to access fields of `annotated` class field. So I would have two classes

```
public class InnerClass {
    private final String innerField = "String";
}
```

and

```
@CustomAnnotation
public class OuterClass {
    private final InnerClass inner = new InnerClass();
}
```

I am getting annotated class `OuterClass` and I can access its field by `getEnclosedElements`. But is it possible to access `InnerClass.innerField` somehow? I have seen some annotations that looks like get fields from inner class but I couldn't find any way of getting it.

Comment: what is `enclosingElements`? did you mean `Class::getDeclaredFields()` ? you can access `innerField` through reflection api

Comment: @SharonBenAsher He is taking about ANNOTATION environemnt.

Comment: @DeanXu, I read the question. I know how Annotations work. I didn't hear about `enclosingElements` nor did come up with any hint in a search.

Comment: @SharonBenAsher See `javax.lang.model.element.Element#getEnclosingElement`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the `TypeElement` from `Elements.getTypeElement` directly

```
TypeElement te = elements.getTypeElement("yourpackage.InnerClass");
ElementFilter.fieldsIn(te.getEnclosedElements()).forEach(System.out::println);
```

If you don't know the `InnerClass` name and need to get the type from `OuterClass`. You can use `Types.asElement` to get `Element` from `TypeMirror`

```
Element outer = ...; // Get your outer class element
VariableElement field = ElementFilter.fieldsIn(outer.getEnclosedElements()).stream().findFirst().get();
Element inner = types.asElement(field.asType());
ElementFilter.fieldsIn(inner.getEnclosedElements()).forEach(System.out::println);
```